# How to display date in kurdish using php

Tags: php, wordpress

In php the date() function displays the date. But I have to display the date in kurdish language.. any one help me.

for example ..have to display the date like this

> ٢\١٢\٢٠١٤

Comment: I think you have to write your own function for this as far as i know! Or if you have only 1 symbol for each number like: `a,b,c,...` -> `0,1,2,...` you could write which symbol matches which number and then you can do a simple str replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your Q is tagged WordPress, you can use [`date_i18n()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n) to retrieve the date in localized format, based on timestamp:

```
echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), time() )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the given string to whatever charset you are using.

This is not bound to kurdish but to any language which cannot be displayed by your systems defauld charset.